# OS X Mavericks extra desktops (spaces) opening seemingly randomly

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control

I don't often use mission control, or extra desktops (spaces). Every so often, I do open mission control by mistake, and I have dozens of spaces showing at the top of the screen.

Is there a shortcut key or something that I am pressing accidentally in my workflow that is opening them? A google search doesn't show anything obvious. Is there a way I can prevent them from being opened at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Command` + `arrows (left, right)` to move between your spaces and you always will be in right place.

Comment: I know how to move between them. The question is why are the dozens (87 at the time of me asking this question) open when I haven't intentionally or knowingly opened them? I don't use them in my day-to-day workflow, but something I am doing must be creating them.

Comment: Hm, mil pardon. So... and you try to close them all? And after some time you have the same thing, right?

Comment: Exactly. As I said in the OP, I very rarely open mission control, so I am not even sure how long it takes for them to start spawning again.

Comment: Excuse me again for off top, but after Steve Jobs pass away Apple's policy in OS is so strange. Bugs are everywhere. Only one thing I understand that if you have a strange bug you should try to re-install system, it works for me in Yosemite (for me it's Apple's bug system number 1). Cheers.